# Локальный минимум в списке

Tags: java, алгоритм, list

Задача заключается в следующем:

> Необходимо реализовать функцию, которая из элементов переданного
>   списка целых чисел составит новый список, состоящий из всех элементов
>   переданного списка за исключением локальных минимумов. Локальный
>   минимум - элемент, который строго меньше соседей слева и справа (для
>   элемента[0] - справа, для последнего - слева). Обращаться к элементам
>   по индексу запрещено, перебирать элементы с помощью цикла for (int
>   value: list) {..}

Проблема следующая:
Если в списке имеются два одинаковых элемента, причем один из них является локальным минимум, то в новый список не добавляются оба (хотя должен не добавиться только тот, который является локальным минимумом).

Ниже прикрепляю фрагмент кода.

```
static List<Integer> list(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer value : list) {
        if (!isLocalMin(list, value)) {
            newList.add(value);
        }
    }
    return newList;
}

static boolean isLocalMin(List<Integer> list, int number) {
    Integer bufferNum = 0;
    Integer bufferLeft = 0;
    for (Integer value : list) {
        if (value == number) {
            bufferLeft = bufferNum;
            bufferNum = number;
        } else {
            if (bufferLeft > bufferNum && value > bufferNum) {
                return true;
            }
            bufferNum = value;
            bufferLeft = bufferNum;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Я исправил ошибку с последним элементом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается одним циклом:

```js
function f(arr) {
  var res = []
  var l, c, r
  var first = true
  
  for (r of arr) {
    if (first) {
      l = Infinity
      c = r
      first = false
    } else {
      if (!(c < l && c < r)) {
        res.push(c)
      }
    
      l = c
      c = r
    }
  }
  
  if (c >= l) {
    res.push(c)
  }
  
  return res
}

var a = Array.from({length:10}, () => Math.random()*100 | 0)
console.log(a.join(", ") + "\n" + f(a).join(", "))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!